# Sheeshuh mayoys (600) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Hi

It's well known that every number has some significance in the Torah, so what is the significance of the number 600 (represented by final mem according to one system of gematria)?

Blessings and success

Comment: How is it humanly possible for any bawlay chawee to downvote such a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the Exodus, Pharaoh pursued the Israelites with **six hundred of his picked chariots**.  [Exodus 14:7]

Answer (score 2):

Noah was **six hundred years old** when the Flood came. [Genesis 7:6]

Answer (score 1):

[Shmuel I 17:7](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.17.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi) - The weight of Golyas's (Goliath) spear head was 600 shekels:

> וחץ [וְעֵ֣ץ] חֲנִית֗וֹ כִּמְנוֹר֙ אֹֽרְגִ֔ים וְלַהֶ֣בֶת חֲנִית֔וֹ **שֵׁשׁ־מֵא֥וֹת שְׁקָלִ֖ים** בַּרְזֶ֑ל וְנֹשֵׂ֥א הַצִּנָּ֖ה הֹלֵ֥ךְ לְפָנָֽיו׃
>
> The shaft of his spear was like a weaver’s bar, and the iron head of his spear weighed **six hundred shekels**; and the shield-bearer marched in front of him.

Answer (score 1):

[Shoftim 3:31](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.3.31?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - The fourth Shofet (Judge) of Israel, Shamgar ben Anas slew 600 Pelishtim (Philistines) with an ox-goad (a saddle spur explains [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Judges.3.31?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Judges.3.31.1&lang2=bi))

> וְאַחֲרָ֤יו הָיָה֙ שַׁמְגַּ֣ר בֶּן־עֲנָ֔ת **וַיַּ֤ךְ אֶת־פְּלִשְׁתִּים֙ שֵֽׁשׁ־מֵא֣וֹת אִ֔ישׁ בְּמַלְמַ֖ד הַבָּקָ֑ר** וַיֹּ֥שַׁע גַּם־ה֖וּא אֶת־יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃ (ס)
>
> After him came Shamgar son of Anath, **who slew six hundred Philistines with an ox-goad**. He too was a champion of Israel.

Answer (score 0):

Noah's ark was 600 cubits long.

> וְזֶ֕ה אֲשֶׁ֥ר תַּֽעֲשֶׂ֖ה אֹתָ֑הּ שְׁלֹ֧שׁ מֵא֣וֹת אַמָּ֗ה אֹ֚רֶךְ
> הַתֵּבָ֔ה חֲמִשִּׁ֤ים אַמָּה֙ רָחְבָּ֔הּ וּשְׁלֹשִׁ֥ים אַמָּ֖ה
> קוֹמָתָֽהּ׃
>
> These are the directions as to how you shall make it: Six hundred feet
> shall be the length of the ark, one hundred feet the’ breadth of it,
> and sixty feet the height of it.